# Can I get arrested for loitering?

Tags: usa, legal

[Loitering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loitering) seems to have incredibly vague definition, according to Wikipedia. It seems that it's illegal, even if you don't seem to be doing anything wrong. In the US, there are signs to this effect, which came to a surprise to me. Can I actually get into trouble if I, well, loiter, whatever loose definition you use?

[image]

<sup>Photo is from personal archive.</sup>

Comment: Undoubtedly an interesting question, but what's the link with this site's topic?

Comment: @MarcelC.: He's obviously a tourist who doesn't want to end up arrested for a vague law

Comment: that specific photo indicates private property (or a government installation, not quite sure how the USPS would be treated) so they can certainly set rules about what you are allowed to do on the site. As a security measure, I'd expect them to try to get rid of people hanging out around the gates and possibly tipping off accomplices about vehicles leaving there that can then be ambushed and robbed elsewhere for example.

Comment: @jwenting: it's hardly the only "No loitering" sign I have seen, and many are without the indication of private property or special security status.

Comment: @mindcorrosive true, but many companies will have reason to not want strangers on their property and after 9/11 many cities and other governments no longer care all that much about what's legal when it comes to "protection against potential terrorists". Just walk around London with a camera and aim it at a police car or underground train, you're in custody and have your camera confiscated very quickly despite there being no law giving anyone rights to do so.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It depends what you're doing, where you're doing it, and (from personal experience) whether you look like a member of $racial_minority.

The loitering laws are in place so that the police can ask you for ID if they think you may be doing something illegal. For example, someone "loitering" on a parking lot can be looking for cars to break into. However, if you're stopped by an officer in the parking lot, show them your ID, and then tell them that you're looking for your car because you're not used to such immense parking lots, not only will all be fine, they may even help you figure out where you parked.

A [Florida lawyer](http://www.floridadefenselaw.com/articles/jul/2012/can-you-be-arrested-loitering-or-prowling) explains that

> You can charged with loitering or prowling, if you are in a place and at a time where normal, law-abiding citizens are not commonly found and which could be construed as posing a threat to property or to others. If you are discovered by a police officer who asks you to identify yourself and you refuse, or you try to conceal your presence, or you immediately flee the scene, the officer may have grounds to charge you with loitering since you did not adequately justify your presence at the location.

Thus, as long as you can identify yourself, you should do fine as a tourist, since you can always justify your presence with "I'm so glad to see you, officer. I'm totally lost". Note that won't work quite as well if you're in a tent [where they don't want you to be camping](http://www.sfbg.com/politics/2012/01/31/arrest-raises-doubts-about-wieners-loitering-ban)

Comment: Yup.  I've had an encounter with a policeman that way--hanging around a construction site after dark.  A construction site (a whole subdivision, not just one house) after dark is roads devoid of cars--a perfect place to let a new driver get practice safely.  He understood, no problem.

Comment: @LorenPechtel A large parking lot is just as effective and safer for the car. :)

Comment: @Karlson: Of course you start with the parking lot.  However, parking lots lack streets.  The construction site provided a more realistic driving situation.  There were multiple blocks worth of territory with nothing of importance about.

Comment: @LorenPechtel And you even got to practise being pulled over by the cops!

Comment: suggestion: change "$racial_minority" to "a racial minority"

Comment: @user253751, please use the edit button under the question and submit an edit, that way it will be taken up by the community. It is by accident that I read your comment, the person who will/would get updated on all comments is OP who has not visited the site for 3 years, so is unlikely to read their messages. And I do not know whether it is a good change, so I am going to let it to the community to decide.

Comment: @Willeke small edits are not for third parties to make.

Answer (score 3):

In America, they don't want people to do anything that disrupts commercial activity. So begging is "out" for example. And "loitering" would be seen in a similar light.

There are signs at many establishments that read something like: "Patrons only, violators [or "loiterers"] are subject to arrest.

If you are in a store, you should be doing business with the store (or look like you are). Stores, and even libraries don't want people sleeping on the premises, or otherwise taking up space if you are not there for the stated purpose of the premise because they want to cater to genuine "customers." That also applies to places like construction sites.

In Nevada, it is a felony to use a computer in a casino to calculate odds (thereby reducing the casino's advantage). Not exactly "loitering," but it does illustrate a point about the "pro-commercial" nature of the American legal system.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about the consequences of loitering, not about whether you can sleep in a store or library or use a computer in a casino.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: If using a computer in a casino, a FELONY, doesn't get you arrested, I don't know what will. And when I talk about begging or other disrupting commercial activity being "out," I'm really talking about the possibility of your getting arrested. That should be clear from the context.

Comment: This just seems like a borderline anti-American rant than an answer.

Comment: @Andy: I am an American, and I am just trying to tell travelers "how it is" in certain parts of the country (even though it probably shouldn't be the case). And why (commercial reasons.) This is particularly true of a country that just elected the most commercially minded President in recent history (although my answer predates the 2016 election).

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason an American can't go on an anti-American rant.   Plenty of people here seem to hate the country.  But a rant is still a rant.

Comment: @Andy: I decapitalized "felony" to tone down the comment. Otherwise, I'm telling it like it is. What I said is objectively true.

Comment: No you're not.  Not even close to objectively true.

Comment: Get real!. This stuff happens in many parts of America every day of the week. (Probably not in Europe.) And America has the highest incarceration rate in the world, both in absolute numbers, and relative to population (only China and India have higher populations, and they have fewer people incarcerated). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_incarceration_rate

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can be arrested for this; you usually won't, but usually isn't always, and you won't know until it's too late. The entire point of such laws existing in the first place is to give the authorities a legal justification to be able to arrest someone, harass them, or leave them alone, whichever they prefer, at a whim, so long as the target is within the specified location.

Note that begging, being homeless, and in some cases even just looking like you're really poor, are all common primary targets for such laws, because passing a "no loitering" ordinance and then enforcing it on anyone who looks homeless (and on no one else) is much better for public relations than a "jail time for being poor" law, so if you are going to be in such a place, avoid looking like you might be homeless, as it will substantially increase the odds of arrest.

Answer (score -2):

You can wander about anywhere at anytime of the day or night without raising the slightest suspicion simply by taking along a dog.